Errores al tratar de conectar a Instancia SQL
Estoy tratando de conectarme a una instancia SQL desde PC A.
Desde mi PC A quiero conectarme a mi Instacia B.
En mi instancia B mi servidor se llama asi:
DESKTOP\CMT_VID
Tabs:
Seguridad= SQL Server And Windows Authentication Mode
Conections= Allow remote connections to this server=yes

SQL Server Configuracion Manager:
SQL Server Network Configuration > TCP/IP=Enabled, Listening All=Yes, IPAddress > IPAddressAll > TCP Port = 1433
SQL Server Browser=Running

Firewall > Inbound new rule = "[WIN10CTM] BROWSER 1434, [WIN10CTM] SQL 1433

Desde mi PC A intento conectar a la instancia así:
Server Type = Database Engine
Server Name = DESKTOP\CMT_VID (Igual intente poniendo el puerto al final asi:DESKTOP\CMT_VID.1433)
Authentification:Windows y SQL Server Authentication

En ambos caso recibo el error:
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Todos los hilos que he leído con este error hablan de la instancia o configuración del TCP/IP mismos que ya tengo configurados en PC B.
Por donde mas puede ir este error?
Espero puedan apoyarme.
Saludos

Probaste de forma local la instancia DESKTOP\CMT_VID, por otro lado verifica que en el firewall que no haya otras reglas bloqueando este tipo de tráfico.
Asegúrate de que las conexiones TCP/IP estén habilitadas tanto en la configuración del servidor SQL como en la configuración de red del servidor.
En el SQL Server Configuration Manager verifica que la instancia esté configurada para aceptar conexiones remotas. Asegúrate también de que el protocolo TCP/IP esté habilitado correctamente para la instancia.
Si no funciona revisa los log de errores en SQLServer en la instancia B

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Error al conectar SQL SERVER vía TCP/IP: Connect timed out

@jachguate revise tu post y todo esta ok la unica forma, telnet, ping, configuraion del firewall, servidor la unica forma en que pude conectarme es como lo comentas en el post usando la IP,Puerto,Instancia

@JDaniel si lo que quieres es conectarte usando el nombre de equipo y es lo que no logras, entonces hay que ver quién es el responsable de resolver ese nombre. Depende de la configuración de tu red. En una red casera típica de Windows, va a ser el servidor WINS, mientras en una red empresarial, puede ser un servidor DNS. Investiga sobre el tema y, al final, si puedes hacer exitosamente un ping NombreEquipo en la línea de comandos, vas a poder conectarte a NombreEquipo\Instancia, siempre que uses el puerto default.
